# How I can activate a LinkButton without click on this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, listview, linkbutton

I want open Outlook if I click on a Button in a ListView. how this...

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com">Send email to user@example.com</a>
```

I have a ...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

without a url. The Url get this LinkButton from the ListView and it works but i don't can activate this LinkButton after this :(

how this...

```
protected void myListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "mailto")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)myListView.Items[index].FindControl("Label2");

        string mailto = lb.Text;

        LinkButton1.PostBackUrl = "mailto:" + mailto;
        LinkButton1.ResolveClientUrl("mailto:" + mailto); //Here?????
    }
}
```

How I can activate the LinkButton wthout click on this?

Comment: Why do you use an ItemCommand for this? Can't you set the mailto: link directly in your listview with eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck on using a button, then set the ClientClick property.  Use `return false;` to cancel the postback.  If you want the postback, then leave it off.

```
LinkButton1.ClientClick = "window.open('mailto:someone@somewhere.com', 'email'); return false;";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<asp:HyperLink />`, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl = "mailto:abc@example.com" Text ="abc@example.com"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use link

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl" runat="server" NavigateUrl = ..." Text ="link"></asp:HyperLink>
```

You can use in code behind as linkbutton, but he offers others functionalities

```
hl.NavigateUrl =  "mailto:" + mailto;
```

Tarasov You find all properties here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use hyperlink instead of link button

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
NavigateUrl="mailto:user@example.com" >HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```